# How to deploy war file to jboss 7.1.1 from jenkins1.573 automatically during build?

Tags: jenkins, jboss7.x, maven-3, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to build a project using `jenkins.upon` successful build my war file should be deployed automatically to jboss deployments folder. But during build I got the following error:
I am using deploy plugin in jenkins.

```
ERROR: Publisher hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher aborted due to exception
org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to create deployer with implementation class org.codehaus.cargo.container.jboss.JBoss7xRemoteDeployer for the parameters (container [id = [jboss7x]], deployer type [remote]).
at org.codehaus.cargo.generic.spi.AbstractGenericHintFactory.createImplementation(AbstractGenericHintFactory.java:154)
at org.codehaus.cargo.generic.spi.AbstractIntrospectionGenericHintFactory.createImplementation(AbstractIntrospectionGenericHintFactory.java:93)
at org.codehaus.cargo.generic.deployer.DefaultDeployerFactory.createDeployer(DefaultDeployerFactory.java:141)
at org.codehaus.cargo.generic.deployer.DefaultDeployerFactory.createDeployer(DefaultDeployerFactory.java:161)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:61)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:116)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:103)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:922)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:895)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:103)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:61)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:772)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:736)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1040)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:685)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1757)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:529)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:234)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.cargo.generic.deployer.DefaultDeployerFactory.createInstance(DefaultDeployerFactory.java:220)
at org.codehaus.cargo.generic.deployer.DefaultDeployerFactory.createInstance(DefaultDeployerFactory.java:43)
at org.codehaus.cargo.generic.spi.AbstractGenericHintFactory.createImplementation(AbstractGenericHintFactory.java:150)
... 19 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.cargo.util.CargoException: Cannot locate the JBoss connector classes! Make sure the required JBoss JARs (or Maven dependencies) are in CARGO's classpath.
More information on: http://cargo.codehaus.org/JBoss+Remote+Deployer
at org.codehaus.cargo.container.jboss.JBoss5xRemoteDeployer.<init>(JBoss5xRemoteDeployer.java:161)
at org.codehaus.cargo.container.jboss.JBoss7xRemoteDeployer.<init>(JBoss7xRemoteDeployer.java:41)
... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.as.controller.client.ModelControllerClient
at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1375)
at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1325)
at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1078)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.cargo.container.jboss.JBoss5xRemoteDeployer.<init>(JBoss5xRemoteDeployer.java:156)
... 27 more
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.cargo.generic.deployer.DefaultDeployerFactory.createInstance(DefaultDeployerFactory.java:220)
at org.codehaus.cargo.generic.deployer.DefaultDeployerFactory.createInstance(DefaultDeployerFactory.java:43)
at org.codehaus.cargo.generic.spi.AbstractGenericHintFactory.createImplementation(AbstractGenericHintFactory.java:150)
at org.codehaus.cargo.generic.spi.AbstractIntrospectionGenericHintFactory.createImplementation(AbstractIntrospectionGenericHintFactory.java:93)
at org.codehaus.cargo.generic.deployer.DefaultDeployerFactory.createDeployer(DefaultDeployerFactory.java:141)
at org.codehaus.cargo.generic.deployer.DefaultDeployerFactory.createDeployer(DefaultDeployerFactory.java:161)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:61)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:116)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:103)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:922)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:895)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:103)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:61)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:772)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:736)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1040)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:685)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1757)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:529)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:234)
Caused by: org.codehaus.cargo.util.CargoException: Cannot locate the JBoss connector classes! Make sure the required JBoss JARs (or Maven dependencies) are in CARGO's classpath.
More information on: http://cargo.codehaus.org/JBoss+Remote+Deployer
at org.codehaus.cargo.container.jboss.JBoss5xRemoteDeployer.<init>(JBoss5xRemoteDeployer.java:161)
at org.codehaus.cargo.container.jboss.JBoss7xRemoteDeployer.<init>(JBoss7xRemoteDeployer.java:41)
... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.as.controller.client.ModelControllerClient
at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1375)
at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1325)
at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1078)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.cargo.container.jboss.JBoss5xRemoteDeployer.<init>(JBoss5xRemoteDeployer.java:156)
... 27 more
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: have you tried doing what [this ticket suggests](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/TEIID-2038), namely editing the admin module

Comment: yes i added dependancy but i didnt find any folder named teiid in jboss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin can't find the `ModelControllerClient`. It looks like a missing dependency on the `org.jboss.as:jboss-as-controller-client`.

Another option would be to use the [`jboss-as-maven-plugin`](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/). Should have similar goals as cargo for deploying.

Comment: yes it is right.thank you for your answer.i had already done with it but forgot to post answer

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue from yesterday , I found the solution.
The solution is very simple. Please follow below steps:

Step 1: Go to "**Manage Jenkins**" --> "**Manage Plugins**" 
Step 2: Install "**Deploy to container Plugin**" (After successful installation you can able to see '*Deploy ear/war to container*' in **Post Build Action** section)
Step 3: [See this image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iP4wN.png)

Step 4: Copy all JBoss module JAR files to Jenkins deploy folder(*jenkns\plugins\deploy\WEB-INF\lib*)

Step 5: Restart your JENKINS


That's it you are done!. It works fine.

Comment: Step1 and 2 are not required, I think they are already available in your jenkins