# Jenkins Post Build Action: Deploy war to JBoss AS 7.x

Tags: jenkins, jboss

I have Googled the following issue but not quite got what exactly to do as I am new to Jenkins. Here is one solution to this on SO itself, I can't comment on answer, due to low reputation.

[How to deploy war file to jboss 7.1.1 from jenkins1.573 automatically during build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25052006/how-to-deploy-war-file-to-jboss-7-1-1-from-jenkins1-573-automatically-during-bui)

It would be really great if somebody provides step by step way out of this:

Caused by: org.codehaus.cargo.util.CargoException: Cannot locate the JBoss connector classes! Make sure the required JBoss JARs (or Maven dependencies) are in CARGO's classpath.
More information on: http://cargo.codehaus.org/JBoss+Remote+Deployer

Edit Updated Pom.xml

```
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
     <testSourceDirectory>test</testSourceDirectory>
     <plugins>
        <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
         </plugin>


      <plugin>
      <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>7.4.Final</version>
      </plugin>




    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use maven you can use maven jboss as plugin. Just add

```
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>7.4.Final</version>
    </plugin>
  <plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

to your project's pom.xml

Then add as post-build step:

```
cd my-ear-or-war-packaged-project
mvn jboss-as:deploy -Djboss-as.port=9999 -Djboss-as.hostname=localhost
```

and the code should deploy in the post build step.

You can also add the execution of the plugin to a dedicated maven profile, which would make the artifact deploy already during the build phase, without the need to create additional build step in jenkins.

Comment: Updated pom.xml, I am using deploy plugin for jenkins

Comment: error during mvn clean install or during jboss-as:deploy?

Comment: Now I used your instructions. I got this error: [ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'jboss-as' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/var/lib/openshift/550d4977e0b8cde60600009e/.m2/repository), central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]

Comment: Needn't do :  cd my-ear-or-war-packaged-project

Comment: Now I get this error:java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012144: Could not connect to remote://jbossews-domain.rhcloud.com:9999. The connection timed out

Comment: my maven deploy command was: Am I missing anything?
mvn jboss-as:deploy -Djboss-as.hostname=jbossews-domain.rhcloud.com -Djboss-as.username=xxxx -Djboss-as.password=xxx

Comment: Ok, you are using JBoss hosted in Openshift, so you probably can't access the JMX port directly. I have not worked with JBoss instances in Openshift, so unfortunately I can't help you. Probably there is some openshift plugin for maven.